Effect of symmetry on length of minimum-weight walk
Let $G=(V,E)$ be a simple complete digraph with $n$ vertices and positive symmetric edge weights $d_{ij}=d_{ji}, i\neq j \in V$. When the weights $d_{ij}, i\neq j \in V$ are metric (they satisfy the triangular inequality), then the length (the number of edges used in the walk; some edges may be counted multiple times) of the minimum-weight closed walk visiting all vertices is $n$, where the optimal walk is a Hamiltonian directed cycle.
For the weights that are not metric, can we provide a tight upper bound on the length of the minimum-weight closed walk? In an elegant answer by @MishaLavrov to my earlier question on the general case,  it turned out that the best bound for the asymmetric case is
$$\left\lfloor \frac{(n+1)^2}{4}\right\rfloor.$$
Is the bound $$2(n-1)$$ correct for the symmetric case, which has been also guessed by Misha?

It seems the bound $2(n-1)$ is obtained in graphs containing a spanning tree subgraph (a number of such subgraphs are depicted in the above figure for $n=6$) with edge weights 1 while the weights of the other edges are set to a suffectinly large positive number.
